# overloading a function for a bunch of types

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, typeclass

Suppose I would like to define arithmetic operators for functional types like `() => Int`, `() => Double` etc in the following manner

```
def + (a : () => Int, b : () => Int) = 
      new (() => Int) { 
              def apply() = a() + b() 
      }
```

Is there any way to avoid boiler plate code in defining similar functions for all possible argument type combinations?
These types can be built-in ones (`Int`, `Long`, `Double`), user-defined ones (like `Currency`, `Quantity` etc), and `Option[T]` where `T` can be any before mentioned types.

```
def + (a : () => Option[Int], b : () => Double) = 
    new (() => Option[Double]) 
        {
            // this specific code could be factored out
            def apply() = 
                a() map { _ + b() }  
        }
```

Comment: Could you provide more examples of user-defined classes you are talking about? Do you imply some restrictions on them (e.g., case classes with one argument, etc)? Otherwise I guess the scope would be too broad.

Comment: I also can't tell exactly what you're trying to do, but it sounds like you're probably reinventing something from scalaz.

Comment: first of all, you can get rid of `new` boilerplate: `def + (a : () => Int, b : () => Int) = () => a() + b()`

Comment: In fact I wouldn't like to impose restriction on user-defined types to be supported (but apparently they are going to be case classes with one argument). I would like to find a solution based on introducing type classes like `trait HasConversion[From, To]{ def convert(x : From) : To }` and `trait Addable[T]{ def plus(x : T, y : T) : T }` but I don't know how to make them work together.

Answer (score 0):

You can create trait which instances define concrete implementation of your operations for particular type. Then require this trait as implicit parameter for your operations and invoke these concrete implementations.

For the example, check sources of [scala.math.Numeric](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Numeric).

Comment: Thank you but I've got impression that scala.math.Numeric and Spire don't solve the problem of mixed arithmetics

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem can be solved by introducing

```
trait PlusDefined[A,B] { 
    type Ret
    def plus(a : A, b : B) : Ret
}
```

and introducing implicit values for different types. My current solution couldn't avoid all boiler-plate code (like explicit overloads for Option[T]) but looks workable:

```
import language.implicitConversions

trait Conversion[From, To]
{
    def convert(from : From) : To
}

object Conversions {

    implicit def toOption[T, U](implicit ev : Conversion[T,U]) 
                 : Conversion[T, Option[U]] =
        new Conversion[T, Option[U]]
        {
            def convert(x : T) = Some(ev.convert(x))
        }
    implicit def toOptionId[T] 
                 : Conversion[T, Option[T]] =
        new Conversion[T, Option[T]]
        {
            def convert(x : T) = Some(x)
        }
    implicit def betweenOptions[T, U](implicit ev : Conversion[T,U]) 
                 : Conversion[Option[T], Option[U]] =
        new Conversion[Option[T], Option[U]]
        {
            def convert(x : Option[T]) = x map { y => ev.convert(y) }
        }

    implicit val int2double     = 
        new Conversion[Int,  Double]{  def convert(x : Int) = x  }

    implicit val int2long       = 
        new Conversion[Int,  Long]  {  def convert(x : Int) = x  }

    implicit val long2double    = 
        new Conversion[Long, Double]{  def convert(x : Long) = x }

}

trait PlusDefined[A,B]
{
    type Ret
    def plus(a : A, b : B) : Ret
}

trait Addable_Level1 {
    implicit def rightConversion[A,B](implicit  c : Conversion[A,B], 
                                      ev : PlusDefined[B,B]) 
                 : PlusDefined[A,B] =
        new PlusDefined[A,B]
        {
            type Ret = PlusDefined[B,B]#Ret
            def plus(a : A, b : B) = ev.plus(c.convert(a), b)
        }

    implicit def leftConversion[A,B](implicit  c : Conversion[B,A], 
                                               ev : PlusDefined[A,A]) 
                 : PlusDefined[A,B] =
        new PlusDefined[A,B]
        {
            type Ret = PlusDefined[A,A]#Ret
            def plus(a : A, b : B) = ev.plus(a, c.convert(b))
        }
}

trait Addable_Level2  extends Addable_Level1
{
    implicit def rightOpt[A,B](implicit  ev : PlusDefined[A,B]) 
                 : PlusDefined[A,Option[B]] =
        new PlusDefined[A,Option[B]]
        {
            type Ret = Option[PlusDefined[A,B]#Ret]
            def plus(a : A, b : Option[B]) = b map { x =>  ev.plus(a,x) }
        }
    implicit def leftOpt[A,B](implicit  ev : PlusDefined[A,B]) 
                 : PlusDefined[Option[A],B] =
        new PlusDefined[Option[A],B]
        {
            type Ret = Option[PlusDefined[A,B]#Ret]
            def plus(a : Option[A], b : B) = a map { x =>  ev.plus(x,b) }
        }
    implicit def bothOpt[A,B](implicit  ev : PlusDefined[A,B]) 
                 : PlusDefined[Option[A],Option[B]] =
        new PlusDefined[Option[A],Option[B]]
        {
            type Ret = Option[PlusDefined[A,B]#Ret]
            def plus(a : Option[A], b : Option[B]) =
                (a,b) match {
                    case (Some(x), Some(y)) => Some(ev.plus(x,y))
                    case _ => None
                }
        }
}

object Addable extends Addable_Level2 {
    implicit def fromNumeric[T : Numeric] 
                 : PlusDefined[T,T] = new PlusDefined[T,T]
    {
        type Ret = T
        def plus(a : T, b : T) = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(a,b)
    }
}
```